# How to Install Parse SDK on ios Swift Projects

Tags: ruby, parse-platform, cocoapods

Im working in on a Swift project and i tried following these [instructions](https://www.back4app.com/docs/ios/parse-swift-sdk) to install Parse Swift and couldn't get past the first step.

I tried

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I kept getting this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.3. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3` and then running the current command again
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Swift Package Manager instead. In Xcode, go to File -> Add Packages and paste this URL in: `https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift`.

If, for some reason, SPM is not a valid option for you, consider installing CocoaPods through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) instead using `brew install cocoapods` as this also installs the latest Ruby version, which CocoaPods requires.

Answer (score 0):

1. rbenv install 3.1.2
2. rbenv global 3.1.2
3. ruby -v
4. sudo gem install cocoapods